# Why can't you use sunlight as the source of changing magnetic flux for Faraday's law?

Tags: maxwell-equations

Why can't you use sunlight as the source of changing magnetic flux for Faraday's law?  Is sunlight not partially made of an undulating magnetic field?

Edit: Use plane polarized sunlight that is made coherent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changing magnetic flux from sunlight is incoherent. For every bit of flux in one direction there is probably another bit of flux in a different direction nearby. They roughly cancel out.

Comment: What about plane-polarized sunlight, that is filtered in some way that coordinates the flux?  Is this possible?

Comment: Polarization won't change that. It will just make it so that everything is either one direction or the opposite with nothing in-between. You will still have as much light on average going "left" vs "right" or "up" vs "down" depending on the orientation of the polarizer

Comment: Thanks Dale, can you make the sunlight coherent somehow to fix this? (Maybe a standing wave.)  I assume the answer is "no."

Comment: Well, you can use a solar panel to power a laser. Does that count?

Comment: Haha I guess so!  I was hoping that maybe it would be possible to trap plane-polarized sunlight in an optical cavity or something.